# Adding response values to specific columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to add the responses from a UI prompt to the next available empty cells across a range of columns.

At most, there would be 4 values that would need to be assigned to the designated cells. Right now, I can get my script to function if I use appendRow. I attempted to use setValue, but I appear to be getting the syntax wrong. I cannot get it to pull the value from the responses I define in the script.

I would like to put the responses from one UI in the next empty cell available in columns F:I and responses from another in L:M. These would all be text responses.

For an example, this is basically what I'm trying to accomplish minus the appendRow function:

```
 function addData() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //get user interface
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //assign active spreadsheet to variable
      var result = ui.prompt(
        'Add Data',
        'Please enter Data',
        ui.ButtonSet.OK); //opens up dialogue box with prompts        
      var button = result.getSelectedButton(); //gets users button click
      var text = result.getResponseText(); //gets users input
      if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
        var result2 = ui.prompt(
          'Enter Base Data',
          'Data:',
          ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); //opens up second prompt if user clicked OK
        var button2 = result2.getSelectedButton(); //gets users button click
        var text2 = result2.getResponseText(); //gets users input
        if (button2 == ui.Button.OK) {
          var result3 = ui.prompt(
            'Enter Input',
            'Input:',
            ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); //opens up third prompt for Input
          var button3 = result3.getSelectedButton(); //gets users button click
          var text3 = result3.getResponseText(); //gets users input
        }
        if (button3 == ui.Button.OK) {
          var result4 = ui.prompt(
            'Enter Summary',
            'Summary:',
          ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); //opens up fourth prompt for Summary
          var button4 = result4.getSelectedButton(); //gets users button click
          var text4 = result4.getResponseText(); //gets users input
    
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //opens sheet
          sheet.appendRow([text, text2, text3, text4]); //adds row with user input values
    
        }else if (button4 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
        // user clicked "Cancel"
        ui.alert('Cancelled Data addition.')
        } else if (button3 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
          ui.alert('Cancelled Data addition.'); //alert if cancelled
        }
      } else if (button2 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
        // user clicked "Cancel".
        ui.alert('Cancelled Data addition.'); //alert if cancelled
      } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
        // user clicked 'X' in the title bar.
        ui.alert('Dialogue box was closed.'); //alert if closed
      }
    }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. It does not have to match the above example at all, as long as it captures responses and records that data in empty cells within the specified range.

Thanks in advance. I already feel silly for having to ask, but nothing I come across fits what I need and I receive Syntax errors when I try what I believe should work.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I attempted to use setValue, but I appear to be getting the syntax wrong. I cannot get it to pull the value from the responses I define in the script.` and your showing script. And also, I cannot understand `I would like to put the responses from one UI in the next empty cell available in columns F:J and responses from another in L:M. `. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your reply. I would like to enter text1, text2, text3 and text 4 into a specific column. F:I is the range. I would like to put the data collected from the prompt starting in the first available cell in column F ending in the first available cell in column I

Answer (score 0):

I faced recently the same issue : that why I made some function helper to make it easier.
You need to create a new file.gs and copy paste it in order to use this utils function available there : https://github.com/SolannP/UtilsAppSsript/blob/main/UtilsGSheetTableHelper.gs

Then you can simply update as bellow :

```js
if (button3 == ui.Button.OK) {
  var result4 = ui.prompt('Enter Summary','Summary:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); 
  //opens up fourth prompt for Summary
  var button4 = result4.getSelectedButton(); 
  //gets users button click
  var text4 = result4.getResponseText(); 

  //init all the cells as range close to A1 having data (not empty)
  var rangeTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getDataRegion();
  var tableHandler = new TableWithHeaderHelper(rangeTable)
  tableHandler.addRawArrayEntry([text, text2, text3, text4]); //add row at the end of the table
    
}
else if(....
```

Please note that the total number of column of our table MUST be the same than value to add.

| column A1 | column B1 | column C1 | column D1 | column E1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HEADER TITLE XX | HEADER TITLE YY | HEADER TITLE | HEADER TITLE ⭐ |  |
| 12 | 34 | 12 | 34 |  |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | 34 |  |

Then
`tableHandler.addRawArrayEntry([text, text2, text3, text4]);`

Comment: I am receiving an error involving table size and when I try to define the data region, I also receive an error. This works on a blank spreadsheet, but I cannot seem to define the table size, location. What values can I enter to get this data shifted to F2 as the initial cell?

Comment: @N01788, the script above is made to work on table with header ! If sheet is empty it wont work... 

Juste add data to 4 column as header (the title of each column, from A1 to D1). It should work then